# Excel Summing Formula Based on Date and Drop Down Selector

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been playing around with a few attempts at getting this working but I'm not getting there.

I have data like this

[image]

And I want to be able to create a total for each Category for each month.  I can get either or working but not using both criteria.

This works for Category (referencing a string value from Outgoings sheet):

```
=SUMIF(B3:B21,Outgoings!A9,C3:C21)
```

This works for month January (referencing the Items sheet for values):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(Items!$A$3:$A$1048576)=1),Items!$C$3:$C$1048576)
```

What I can't seem to figure out is combining the two criteria into one function.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$1048576=Outgoings!$A$9)*(MONTH(Items!$A$3:$A$1048576)=1)*Items!$C$3:$C$1048576)`?

Comment: Hmm, Excel doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: This is working for me at the moment, but it appears to be pretty slow when adding data.  ```=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(Items!$A$3:$A$1048576)=1) * (Items!$B3:$B1048576=A9), Items!$C$3:$C$1048576)```

Comment: Try to refer only to the part of the column actually containing data (e.g A3:A55) instead of the whole column.

Comment: That's a very obvious thing to do that I didn't think of.  Duh!